# python - two lines, one command.

Tags: split, keyboard, command, line

I have forgotten the command. 
for a variable, I want to split it up into multiple lines like this:

```
    aminoacid={'ATT':'I','ATC':'I','ATA':'I',
           'CTT':'L','CTC':'L','CTA':'L','CTG':'L','TTA':'L','TTG':'L',
           'GTT':'V','GTC':'V','GTA':'V','GTG':'V','TTT':'F','TTC':'F',
           'ATG':'M',
           'TGT':'C','TGC':'C',
           'GCT':'A','GCC':'A','GCA':'A','GCG':'A',
           'GGT':'G','GGC':'G','GGA':'G','GGG':'G',
           'CCT':'P','CCC':'P','CCA':'P','CCG':'P',
           'ACT':'T','ACC':'T','ACA':'T','ACG':'T',
           'TCT':'S','TCC':'S','TCA':'S','TCG':'S','AGT':'S','AGC':'S',
           'TAT':'Y','TAC':'Y',
           'TGG':'W',
           'CAA':'Q','CAG':'Q',
           'AAT':'N','AAC':'N',
           'CAT':'H','CAC':'H',
           'GAA':'E','GAG':'E',
           'GAT':'D','GAC':'D',
           'AAA':'K','AAG':'K',
           'CGT':'R','CGC':'R','CGA':'R','CGG':'R','AGA':'R','AGG':'R',
           'TAA':'STOP','TAG':'STOP','TGA':'STOP'}
```

but I forgot the keyboard command to do it. can any of you help ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear to me, what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe you are looking for [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint).

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(aminoacid)
```

Your example doesn't need it AFAIK, but you can continue a logical line with a [backslash (\)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining).

Comment: I simply want to split the line, so it doesn't take up 10000 cm in length, but still counts as one action.

Comment: So does pprint what you want?

Comment: no, I don't want to print it. I am talking about the script itself.

Comment: @TheGamingEngi Sorry for the late reply. I think I get it now. I update my answer.